# Airplay stopped working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, appletv, airplay

All of a sudden none of my ios devices are able to connect to the Apple TV via Airplay. The Airplay icon shows up in the Control center on my Iphone 5s and my ipad 3. If I choose to airplay, the music doesnt stream to my Apple TV. It tries to stream, but after about 5 secs, it disconnects from Airplay.
I cannot mirror my ios devices either. Interestingly, I can mirror my Macbook Pro displat to the Apple TV. But that is the extent of it.
I have the latest updates on my Apple TV, my iPhone 5S, ipad 3 and my Macbook Pro.
I have even tried factory resetting my Apple TV and all my ios devices. But none of that has helped.
Anyone experiencing this? Please help.

Comment: What Airport Utility do you have ?

Comment: I don't use the Airport utility

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok. I think I have found a solution. If you have a dual-frequency router like I do, all you need to do is go into your router settings and set different SSIDs for your 2.4GHz and 5Ghz networks. Doing that has fixed my airplay issue instantly. Enjoy!!